# Angles of inward pointing normal vector on sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am writing a solar system simulation and I want the camera to be able to freely move on a sphere while always facing the sun. The moving part is pretty easy. But how do I calculate the angles of the inward pointing normal vector, i.e. how do I make the camera face the sun. If I fix one axis and let the camera move on a circle this is also not so complicated. But I am stuck translating this problem to 3 dimensions. In the following I will also make use of spherical coordinates $(r, \phi, \theta)$

At the beginning the camera is at position (-r, 0, 0) for some fixed radius r. So if I let the camera move around the z-axis at 0, the angle of the camera should be $(0, 0, \pi -\phi)$.

But how do I determine the angle, if I am at an arbitrary point $(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), r\cos(\theta))$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly simple using Cartesian coordinates. So if the camera location is $(x,y,z)$, then the vector from sun to camera is $(x,y,z)$, the vector from camera to sun is $(-x,-y,-z)$.

Then you can translate this vector back to the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ system.
$$
(x,y,z)\mapsto (-x,-y,-z)\\
(r,\phi,\theta)\mapsto (r,\pi+\phi,\pi-\theta)
$$
You may want to mod $2\pi$ if you have certain range convention.

Comment: My problem is that I can't implement your solution. What I can do is move the camera to a point on the sphere and then rotate the camera certain angles around the x, y and z axis. How do I determine these angels? For example if I move around the z-axis the angels will be $(0, 0, \pi - \phi)$.

Comment: So you cannot directly set the angle for the camera? (line ofvsight?)

Comment: Can you do reflection to your camera angle?

Comment: What engine are you using? Like blender?

Comment: I can move the camera to a specific point and then rotate the camera in any direction. I am not quite sure what you mean with line of sight. I am using Ursina engine

Comment: To implement my solution you want to rotate 180 degree across z axis, then reflect the vector across xy plane.

Comment: So let's say I move from $(-r,0,0)$ to a point $(x, y, z)$ on the r-Sphere. The camera  vector should be $(x+r, y, z)$ at this point. How do I reflect this vector across xy? I don't even know what that means actually.

Comment: Reflect across xy plane in cartecian coordinate basically means $(x,y,z)\to(x,y,-z)$